# Is it true that $P_f(k)\simeq C_{~^df}(k)\sqcup C_{~^d f_p}(k)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ be an homogeneous degree $p$ polynomial and let $~^d\! f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be defined by:

$$~^d\! f(x_1, \ldots, x_n):=f(x_1, \ldots, x_n, 1).$$

Let $P_f(k)$ be the projective curve defined by $f$ and let $C_{~^d\!f}(k)$ be the affine curve defined by $~^d\!f$. Is it true that there is an identification:

$$P_f(k)\simeq C_{~^df}(k)\sqcup C_{~^d f_p}(k)$$

where $C_{~^d f_p}(k)$ is the algebraic curve defined by the degree $p$ component of the polynomial $~^df$?

For instance, consider the degree 2 homogeneous polynomial:

$$f(x, y, z)=xy-z^2$$

Then $$~^d f(x, y)=xy-1.$$
In this case the degree 2 part of $~^d f$ is: $$~^ df_2(x, y)=xy.$$

Notice:

$$P_f(k)=\{(a: b: c): c^2=ab\},$$
whereas $$C_f(k)=\{(a, b): ab=1\}$$ and $$C_{~^df_2}(k)=\{(a, b): ab=0\}.$$

Furthermore:

$$P_f(k)=\{(a: b: c): c^2=ab\}=\{(a: b: 0): ab=0\}\sqcup \{(a: b: 1): ab=1\},$$
from which follows the identification. Is it true in general?

Thanks.

Comment: almost unrelated: what exactly is the relation between a union and a disjoint union?

Comment: If you take a homogeneous polynomial in $n+1$ variables, the zero set is a hypersuface and not a curve unless $n=2$. Care to explain?

Comment: @Mohan sorry, it was a terminology issue, I had the bidimensional case in mind..

Comment: @clathratus every disjoint union is an union, but not every union is disjoint. The notation $A=X\sqcup Y$ means $A=X\cup Y$ and $X\cap Y=\phi$.

Comment: What have you tried? The statement is correct and easy to prove.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prove it, so I'll share it here:

Notice that:

$$\begin{align*}
P_f(k)&=\{(a_0: \ldots: a_n): f(a_0, \ldots, a_n)=0\}\\
&=\{(a_0: \ldots: 1): f(a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}, 1)=0\}\sqcup \{(a_0: \ldots: a_{n-1}: 0): f(a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}, 0)=0\}\\
&=\{(a_0: \ldots: a_{n-1}: 1): {}^d f(a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1})=0\}\sqcup \{(a_0: \ldots: a_{n-1}: 0): f(a_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}, 0)=0\}
\end{align*}.$$

The first part is clearly in bijection with $C_{~^d\!f}(k)$, whereas the second part is in bijection with $C_{~^d\! f_p}(k)$ where $p$ is the degree of $f$.